# Как брать из массива по 4 числа и записывать в переменную

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Имеются входные данные из массива:
2 2 1 3 4 5 6 8
Нужно записывать в переменные a b c d по 4 числа, то есть 2 группы 2 2 1 3 и 4 5 6 8. При этом массив может состоять из (n % 4 == 0) чисел. Как это сделать на c++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, вы хотите что-то типа

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i+=4)
{
    a = array[i];
    b = array[i+1];
    c = array[i+2];
    d = array[i+3];
}
```